# Could not evaluate: certificate verify failed while using ssl proxy

Tags: centos5, puppet, puppetmaster

One of our machines was recently put behind an SSL proxy and since then I can't connect to puppet with "Could not evaluate: certificate verify failed."

I have checked that the dates match, regenerated the certificates but to no avail.

Debugging the verification with "openssl s_client  -showcerts -connect puppetmaster:puppetmasterport" shows "Verify return code: 0 (ok)"

Initially the Proxy SSL Certificate was not recognized with a "Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)" problem which was then fixed with the answer in the question: [Adding root certificate to CentOS 5](https://serverfault.com/questions/437375/adding-root-certificate-to-centos-5)

Comment: check also the time set on the master and your agent.

Comment: Thanks for the addition, I should've specified I checked the date AND time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have solved my problem:

> you need to add the top level ca pub key to it to
>   /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem

Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/puppet-users/VVGkYArpYfI